# Bert Config: Num attention heads

Tags: huggingface-transformers, encoder-decoder

I am using the BertConfig() to create a encoder decoder model in the following way:

```
encoder = BertConfig()
decoder = BertConfig()
config = EncoderDecoderConfig.from_encoder_decoder_configs(encoder, decoder)
bert2bert = EncoderDecoderModel(config=config)
bert2bert.config.decoder.is_decoder = True
bert2bert.config.decoder.add_cross_attention = True

bert2bert.config.encoder.num_attention_heads = 12
print(bert2bert.encoder.num_parameters(only_trainable=True),bert2bert.encoder.config.num_attention_heads)
```

With default attention heads 12 the trainable parameters and attention heads at encoder are as below

86742528, 12

However when I try to change the number of attention heads to 4, the number of trainable parameters does not change while the value for number of attention heads changes (as below). Can anyone help me out?

```
bert2bert.config.decoder.add_cross_attention = True
bert2bert.config.encoder.num_attention_heads = 4
print(bert2bert.encoder.num_parameters(only_trainable=True), bert2bert.encoder.config.num_attention_heads)
```

(86742528, 4)

Comment: What is the original problem that you're trying to solve? Is it to reduce the number of parameters, or simply limit processing to the (first? last?) four heads?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to increase/decrease the number of attention heads. As per my understanding , if i increase or decrease the num of attention heads the parameters should also increase/decrease, which i didn't observe in my case. Also, i believe, the attention heads would change to 4 for all encoder layers

Comment: To my knowledge Bert is used just as encoder